# Can I import/use a bash function in awk?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have a fairly large bash function library that I use in an application. The library gets imported as an environment file. Since the functions are exported, I can use these functions in other bash scripts without any issues.

However I have another issue where I need to use an awk scriptlet and I want to be able to use a couple of functions from the bash library if possible.

So in short I want to be able to do one of the two things:

1. Use the function in the bash environment file in awk
2. Import bash environment file inside awk script and use any variables and/or
   functions that are exported using that environment file.

Works:

```
[root@test@Test1001 scripts]# . mfg.env
[root@test@Test1001 scripts]# set -o posix;OSMAJVER=12 EVMAJVER=11 EVMINVER=1 SYSTEM_ARCH=SSA HOST=test;check_flag RAD
[root@test@Test1001 scripts]# echo $?
0
```

Doesn't work:

```
[root@test@Test1001 scripts]# . mfg.env
[root@test@Test1001 scripts]# awk -v st=ssa -v 'env=OSMAJVER=12 EVMAJVER=11 EVMINVER=1 SYSTEM_ARCH=SSA HOST=test' -f /tmp/s1.awk /tmp/template.mf
bash: check_flag: No such file or directory 127
```

s1.awk

```
BEGIN {
  FS=":"
  if (system("set -o posix;"env)!=0) {
    print "***ERROR - ENV string not valid to shell - cannot continue"
    exit 1
  }
}

/^[[:space:]]*#/{next}
/^[[:space:]]*$/{next}

{
  # field 3 processing
  n_a=split($3,a_st,",")
  # field 4 re-glue around ":" if required
  cmd=$4
  for (i=5; i<=NF; i++) cmd=cmd":"$i
  if (cmd) cmd="set -o posix;"env";"cmd
  f=0;for (i=1; i<=n_a && !f; i++) if (a_st[i]==st) f=1
  print "CMD: "cmd
  if ($3=="" || $3=="*" || f)
  system(cmd)
}
```

mf file:

```
text:S3:rcs,ssa:check_flag RAD
```

I want to be able to process the above line only if the "check_flag RAD" returns true.

Comment: Could you make this example a MCVE -- which requires that the code be **complete** and **verifiable**? As it is, we have no idea what's included in `s1.awk`, and so can't write code to show better-practice alternatives to what it's doing.

Comment: @ac1982 I think your statement above that "I can use these functions in **other bash scripts** without any issues" (emphasis mine) says it all - **awk is not bash**, it is a completely separate tool that you can call from bash, just like you can call a C program from bash but that doesn't make C bash either and you wouldn't expect to be able to access bash functions from a C program.

Comment: Frankly, given the code shown, I don't see the "need to use" awk at all. What are you doing in the awk that you couldn't do in native bash?

Comment: Charles, Following your first suggestion I re-wrote some of this to call the function in bash. I'm only using awk to split the fields and rest is taken care by the bash while loop. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, you cannot.**

You *can* use `export -f` to export the function from your parent shell, and then run another instance of bash from awk as a child process. However, this is near the very height of hackery; given more details on what you actually intend to accomplish, we could almost certainly find a better-practice approach.

A better-practice approach is to structure your awk script to write a stream which your shell-native code can read from and operate over -- see [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for best-practices around reading from an input stream field-by-field.